# dialog box not displaying correctly or closing after settimeout function

Tags: jquery, dialog, widget

I am fairly new to jquery, but I have used the dialog widget before.  The dialog box opens fine except its not in the center of the screen, its in the upper left hand corner of the screen.  Ive never had to specify where on the screen to display when I used the dialog before.  And the other problem is after I open it, I have a setTimeout function to close it after a few seconds.  Ive used this same function on other dialogs and its worked fine.  But this dialog doesnt close.  Here ia my code:

Note *** The button is in fact getting updated to show VERIFIED, the dialog does open, it just doesnt recognize the setTimeout function.  Thanks for the help!

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/voter_update',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false, 
    data: {verify: verify,csea_id:csea_id,local:local}, 
    success: function(data){
        //alert('Success! - Record Updated');
        $("#btnSpan").html('VERIFIED');

        var dialogData="<div id='record_status_dialog' align='center'><font color='red'>Success!  Record Updated.</font></div>";
    
        $("#record_status_dialog").html(dialogData);
        $("#record_status_dialog").dialog("open");
            
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("#record_status_dialog").dialog("close");
        },2500);
```

Comment: What dialog are you using? Where do we find the documentation?

Comment: The jQuery dialog widget.  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your javascript is ok. This snippet shows that the dialog opens and closes after 2.5 seconds. Here the ajax `error` is used, for illustration only, since the request fails. But that doesn't matter since this is only a proof-of-concept.

One thing that differs from your code is that the dialog is first initialized before opening. But I think you already got that covered somewhere else in your code.

```
$("#record_status_dialog").dialog({}).dialog("open");
```

As you can see, it works as expected. Or did I miss something?

```js
$(function(){
    
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false, 
        data: {verify: 1}, 
        error: function(data){
            alert(data);
            //alert('Success! - Record Updated');
            $("#btnSpan").html('VERIFIED');
    
            var dialogData="<div id='record_status_dialog' align='center'><font color='red'>Success!  Record Updated.</font></div>";
        
            $("#record_status_dialog").html(dialogData);
            $("#record_status_dialog").dialog({}).dialog("open");
                
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $("#record_status_dialog").dialog("close");
            },2500);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="record_status_dialog"></div>
<span id="btnSpan"></span>
```